# Colocar menu fixo no Blogspot

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou tentando colocar um topo fixo no Blogspot, porém sem sucesso. Não sei exatamente o que acontece, mas o javascript não funciona.

Link do código completo: https://jsfiddle.net/6ovjnhor/

Agora vou mostrar pra vocês o javascript que estou utilizando:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var nav = $('#navi-arlina');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 170) {
        nav.addClass("menu-fixo");
      } else {
        nav.removeClass("menu-fixo");
      }
    });
  }); 
  </script>
```

Nesse código a `div "navi-arlina"` adicionar a outra div ao chegar no 178 px.

```
.menu-fixo {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Segue o código do menu:

```
<header>
  <nav id='navi-arlina' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement'>
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <label>MENU</label>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='link' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Notícias</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='link' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Downloads</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='link' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Coleções Sims Center</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='link' itemprop=''><span itemprop='name'>Para os Sims</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='link' itemprop=''><span itemprop='name'>Objetos</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='link' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Lotes</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='link' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>The Sims 4</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='link' itemprop='link'><span itemprop='name'>Ajuda e Suporte</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='link' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Downloads</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='link' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Coleções Sims Center</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Nossos Portais</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='link' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Página Do Facebook</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='link' itemprop=''><span itemprop='name'>Grupo Do Facebook 1</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='link' itemprop=''><span itemprop='name'>Grupo Do Facebook 2</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='link' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Canal do Youtube</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='link' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Séries Sims Center</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Por favor, me ajudem!!! Ficarei eternamente grato!

Comment: Vinicius, dê uma olhada aqui neste código que encontrei, estou meio sem tempo agora, precisa de uns retoques para checar o `width`. Sempre deve dar uma ajuda. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hc0v9637/)

Comment: Ai amigo quero mesmo te agradecer, eu usei o meu código, porém descobri o problema graças a você. Eu tinha esquecido de colocar a biblioteca do Jquery. AHSUHAUHS

Comment: Acontece-me muitas vezes amigão. Hahah  Um abraço boa sorte